# How to add MySQL Query data to a Global Variable in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

My Question is about How to add MySQL Query data to a Global Variable in Nodejs?

Or is there a way I can access the data of the Query outside the function?

Comment: what d you mean by global variable? Are you trying to bind the result set from MySQL to some global nodejs variable or you will declare a global variable and bind it to result set.?

Comment: what you can do is add the query to a method and return the result saving it to the variable you want `var globalVariable = getSomeData();`

Comment: Just a Nodejs variable declared before the function declaration